# Always need to optmize when i changed somthing in web.php laravel8

Tags: laravel

Every time when I changed something in web.php file in the laravel 8 project  I need to run

```
PHP artisan optimize
```

can anyone tell me what is the solution by default? I don't need to optimize every time or every time I open that project.

Comment: what happens if you don't run optimization?

Comment: ```php artisan optimize``` command will cache your ```events```, ```views```,```cache```,```routes```,```Configuration``` so if your application is in local environment don't cache these. To remove all from cache you run ```php artisan optimize:clear```

Comment: when I add a new URL in web.php if I don't optimize the new URL is not found. @TirdadAbbasi

Comment: Thanks for your solution I know "php artisan optimize:clear" this cmd work perfect but is there something where I don't need to use that cmd @ManojKiranAppathurai

Comment: are you caching routes in development environment ?

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai I don't know but maybe that's the reason. have you any solution for that how to remove that in the development enviroment.

Comment: if you don't cache anything you don't need to clear it whenever it changes. But since you have cached you need to clear it and don't recache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically clearing the cache, and caching again. To disable:

`php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: Yes, thanks for your reply. I already did that but didn't update this post.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. If you don't need to optimize every time in your development environment just write this command

```
PHP artisan route:clear
```

then you don't face that issues.

If you want to go back to your previous state like you should need to optimize or just upload your app in live then just command this.

```
PHP artisan route:cache
```

I hope this will help you ‍

Comment: I'd suggest to _not_ cache anything on your development machine, since you often make changes. Only cache on your production server

Comment: @brombeer thank you brother, could you give me a suggestion on how to remove all cache without any command or one command than not need to modify anything again before upload on server